# Add page number with total page number on each page?

Tags: page-numbering

I am using `\pagestyle{plain}` to add page number to each page in its bottom. If I want something like " page number / total page number" or " page number out of total page number", how shall I do that?

Comment: I hope you don't insist to use `\pagestyle{plain}` and still want to get the desired result. Please see the solution below.

Answer (score 27):

**Solution Idea**

1. Use package [`lastpage`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lastpage) to define the label `LastPage`,
   allowing us to refer to the last page  via `\pageref{LastPage}`.
2. Use [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr) to control your footer.

**The Solution**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

% Uncomment to remove the header rule
% \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image]

**Further Tweaking**

1. If you really like it *plain*, perhaps you will want to use `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` (and may be
   `\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}`) as well to get rid of the rules.
2. Use of `fancyhdr` actually gives you a ton of other controls which
   should be rewarding. Please see the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) for further details.

Comment: You probably want to add \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} unless using a header.

Comment: Yes, all those tweakings are definitely possible. I left them for the end user. Please note that I did not reset the header-footer using `\fancyhf{}`. That was intentional, along with the rules.

Comment: Right but setting \pagestyle{fancy} adds a header rule which is not present with \pagestyle{plain} so if the idea is to show a solution which *just* does what's asked, I guess I thought you'd nullify the rule added by changing the pagestyle. But of course you're right that the user will need to read the documentation to tweak to their liking.

Comment: @cfr Get your point and agreed upon. Added a few lines to the end of my answer.

Comment: \footrulewidth is 0pt by default though it does no harm to show how to change it, of course.

Comment: In order to use \fancyfoot{} you need to use \pagestyle{fancy} first such that the footer could take effect.

Comment: @Jason Yes, indeed. Please note the line `\pagestyle{fancy}` in my solution.

Comment: @Masroor It's interesting that the `\pagestyle{fancy}` could run after `\fancyfoot{}` which is a bit anti-intuitive for me from programming point of view, hence I tried to point out for other newbies like me.